# Weird Behavior with Dart Lists

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three separate code segments that are evaluating to values that are not expected. The first segment is an implementation of a circular buffer where when pushing a new value I want to change each x value to be 0 to (-size) so I can plot these with the most recent value being at 0 and the oldest at -size

My first implementation was just to push the new value to my index `i` which is iterated like `i = (i + 1) % size;` and then fix each x-coordinate as follows:

```
for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
  int temp = (size - (x - i)) % size;
  buffer[(size - (x - i)) % size].x = -x;
}
```

The problem is is that changes both `buffer[temp]` and `buffer[size-temp]` for some reason so I have duplicate values everywhere but the center. I then tried just always pushing onto the beginning of the list and then shifting each element to towards the end by 1 like so:

```
for (int i = size - 1; i > 1; i--) {
  Data_Point_Line_Plot temp = buffer[i - 1];
  temp.x = -i;
  buffer[i] = temp;
}
```

However this makes every element except for `buffer[0]` equal to each other with the x changing each iteration of the loop. Finally I have tried a third approach where I just go through and decrement each x value in the list everytime I push a new one like below:

```
buffer[i] = Data_Point_Line_Plot(x: 1, y: data);
iterate_index();
for (Data_Point_Line_Plot element in buffer) {
  print(element.x);
  int x = element.x;
  element.x = x - 1;
}
```

This gives me all types of crazy numbers, some positive, some many times more negative than `size`

Can someone help me understand if this is typical Dart List behavior and I misunderstand them or if there is another issue.

Comment: You are aware that your list contains references to objects and not the object itself? So multiple positions in your list can point to the same object. So if you make a modification on one object, it will look like it happens at multiple positions in your list. E.g. your second example where you copy the reference to an object and inserts it into another index. After this, you now have two positions in your list that points to the same object.

Comment: @julemand101 Thank you, I figured it was something to do with references rather than value. How would I get and insert by value? Would I need to create a new object in that index each time?

Comment: The safest you can do it make your object immutable and therefore require to make a new object each time you are trying to update the state of the object (like `String` and `int` works). Alternative, you need to be aware of updating the right objects in your list and prevent the copying of references.